# map physical port of switch to machine address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, switch

I would like to know which ethernet port is corresponding to which ip or mac address. 
The web interface of my switch (netgear FS750t2) informs me about which physical port is currently active but not the corresponding mac address. Is there a way to get that from unix command line for example (I read about snmpwalk but can't figure out how to make i work, I got a timeout)?

Comment: You want the [ARP table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) .. this maps which mac to which ip, but it won't tell you on what port it is; that's not a function a "dumb" switch can do. In that even you'll need to trace the cable to the port.

Comment: You can use `ip addr` to list all network interfaces together with their MAC and IP addresses. Depending on your switch, it may use a single network interface and MAC address for all ports, or different interfaces and MAC addresses for each port. *If* there are different MAC addresses, usually they use some obvious numbering scheme, so it shouldn't be too hard to match them to ports.